# Meaing of the sentence in context

Tags: meaning

Context:

> But as young boy in Sicily at the early age of nine he had often gone
>   hunting with his father, had often fired the heavy shotgun called
>   *lupara*. 
>   **It was his skill with the *lupara* even as a small boy that had** 
>   **brought the sentence of death upon him by his father's murders**

urders

I don't understand the last sentence. Did the small boy had brought the sentence? What's that got to do with the shortgun? Couldn't you explain the point?

Comment: Are you sure the last word is **murders** and not **murderers**? As far as I remember, this sentence is from the novel *The Godfather* and the last word was *murderers*.

Comment: I don't think that you have enough context

Answer (score 1):

'with the lupara' just clarifies which skill.  'even as a small boy' and 'by his father's murderers' are also added details.  The main structure then, is "It was his skill that had brought the sentence of death".  In other words, he was to be killed because of his talent.